# Set width of child elements in flex container/parent div

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible, using flex, to set the width of children elements in the style of the their parent div?

For example I want each element in a flex container to stretch 1/3 of the container, or 1/2, or 100% width. They would all have equal widths. The width is a dynamic value which can change.

This issue is, I can add dynamic style values only to the `.flex-container` div. I can't add anything dynamic to `.element` divs.

So I can't do this...

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="element" style="width: 33%"></div>
  <div class="element" style="width: 33%"></div>
  etc...
</div>
```

Only..

```
<div class="flex-container" style="some value that will set children divs to 1/3 width of container, or 1/2, etc)">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  etc...
</div>
```

My CSS for the flex container:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  // I can't add dynamic styles to this like width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dynamically set the width.
Then use media queries to change them depending on your window size.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}
.element {
  width: 33.33%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.element:nth-of-type(1) {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: red;
}
.element:nth-of-type(2) {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: green;
}
.element:nth-of-type(3) {
  align-self: stretch;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="element">
    Test Element 1
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    Test Element 2
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    Test Element 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned, I can't add any dynamic width to the `.element` div. It has to be in the parent only. Anything dynamic.

Comment: I dont understand what situation you would have the ability to set the parent but no the client. Do you have access to the css? If so, i don't see why you wouldn't be able to override the child element width

Comment: I gave a basic example to keep it simple

Comment: In your case, using just the html style attribute would not be enough to apply a style change to a child element. Take a look here - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/ the style attribute will only affect the element it is added too. You would need to add your own style sheet, and use the code I provided earlier